# Yii2 cache of grid view

Tags: caching, gridview, yii2

I have a relatively complex query across 8 tables which returns up to 10,000 records with 20 columns. These are then displayed in a GridView

The user repeatedly sorts and filters the GridView - causing a page reload - in order to rank the data. One column contains an Ajax “five star” rating function  and the user then marks each row: one star to five stars

Naturally, this isn’t the fastest loading page so I was wondering if I could use caching to accelerate the page load but don’t know if this can be done considering the filtering and marking

Can caching be used in this example? The data in the 19 columns are always the same (the user cannot change the data) but the user constantly changes the rating in the 20th column

Can I cache the 19 columns and filter / sort after??

Can I cache the 19 columns and join the rating column thereafter??

Many thanks

Comment: Technically it's possible to cache the query result of your query and do the sorting/filtering in php. But you will probably end up with even worse performance then when you let mysql handle filtering/sorting without caching of results. Things you might want to consider instead of caching: 1) Optimization of sql query. 2) Properly set indexes 3) Denormalization 4) Pagination

Comment: Thanks. I have used temporary tables and denormalisation in the past with good effect. I will go that route again.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily use the [PageCache filter](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-filters-pagecache) behavior of yii2 to easily cache pages.

Just add the following code to your controller and fit the dependency and variation properties to your needs.

```php
public function behaviors()
{
    return [
        'pageCache' => [
            'class' => 'yii\filters\PageCache',
            'only' => ['index'],
            'duration' => 60,
            'dependency' => [
                'class' => 'yii\caching\DbDependency',
                'sql' => 'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM post',
            ],
            'variations' => [
                \Yii::$app->language,
            ]
        ],
    ];
}
```

Comment: Thanks! If the user filters the data will the page still load from cache??? My understanding is that the change will cause a full query

Comment: somehow you have to pass the filter keys and values to the variations field and this way even the filtered results will be cached